# pipe into if then in csh/tcsh

Tags: shell-script, pipe, tcsh, csh

I would like to have a csh script to test a variable between two pipes. For example (the incoming resembles a json file but without the newlines and indentations):

```
set debug = 1
cat test.inp | if ($debug) then (jq '.response' | tee test2.json) else python -m json.tool endif > test.output
```

The idea is that whatever the value of the variable debug, the output is saved in `test.output`. But the way I wrote this leads to the error:

> if: Improper then.

Is there any way to do this in csh/tcsh (as there seems to be in sh/bash)?

Comment: In bash at least the parentheses would not be necessary around the jq part, but you would need a semi-colon after `($debug)`—seems like you need to check csh’s grammar or switch to bash

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `bash` syntax is almost entirely unlike that of the `csh` shells. Don't try applying one to the other.

Comment: @roaima agreed, wasn’t trying to. Just spotting differences, and suggesting that grasping the csh grammar would solve the problem. I know bash intimately; csh, hardly at all.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468284/5132 .

Comment: Thanks to both Ben and roaima for spotting two csh mistakes, 1) the semi-column and 2) the missing endif. These are now corrected in the edited version of the post.

Comment: Is `if ($debug) then (jq '.response' | tee test2.json) else python -m json.tool endif` syntactically correct? If not, that needs to be addressed first.

Answer (score 0):

Piping to control structures is an error in C Shell. The workaround to pipe to control structures is to create a script or FIFO file. Here's an example as file.

```
echo '\
# Functions\
alias function '\''( set argv = ( \\\!* ) ; source ~/.cshfuncs )'\' >> ~/.cshrc
echo 'switch ("$1")\
  case 'myfunc':\
    shift\
    if ("$1") then\
      ( jq '.response' | tee test2.json )\
    else\
      python -m json.tool\
    endif\
    exit\
  default:\
    echo "Function $1 not set."\
    exit\
endsw' > ~/.cshfuncs
```

And here's an example as FIFO.

```
mkfifo ~/fifo
echo 'if ("$?debug") then\
( jq '\''.response'\'' | tee test2.json )\
else\
python -m json.tool\
endif' > ~/fifo & cat test.inp | ( set debug ; source ~/fifo ) > test.output
```